# How make EJS IF/ELSE evaluate correctly

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

My variable 'answer' is coming back as the string 'success', and is printing to the view correctly as such.

But the IF/ELSE statement is always evaluating to the ELSE and showing the 'no' instead of the 'yes'. What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

```
<h3><%= answer %> </h3>
<% if (answer == 'success') { %>
   <p>yes</p>
<% } else { %>
   <p> no</p>
<% } %>
```

Comment: Are you sure there's no extra characters like spaces in your `answer`? Try using `answer.trim() == 'success'` in your `if` statement.

Comment: There's no way to tell with the information provided. Double-check your string content.

Comment: Thanks solved it THANKS!!! :) I was thinking it was new line or something!

Answer (score 0):

are you sure are sending the value of success correctly? Here's is what I have done and getting the expected `yes`.

**index.js**

```
const express = require('express');

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;


app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.render("test", {answer: 'success'});
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`listening on port ${ port }`);
});
```

**test.ejs**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h3><%= answer %> </h3>
    <% if (answer == 'success') { %>
       <p>yes</p>
    <% } else { %>
       <p> no</p>
    <% } %>
</body>
</html>
```

and result

[image]